# Problem writing NSData in my device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata

Can someone explain me why my code doesn't work?

```
//get the documents directory:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


//make a file name to write the data to using the
//documents directory:
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/subscriptions", documentsDirectory];
[dataReply writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:NO];




NSData *getData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName];
```

infact if I try

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:getData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

while if I load myData without save it to my device it works! (So I'm sure that my data is not empty)

Comment: define "works". define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


//make a file name to write the data to using the
//documents directory:
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/subscriptions", documentsDirectory];
[dataReply writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:NO];


Nsdata *getData=[fullFileName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```