# How to use NSUserDefaults to allocate space dynamically?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I ve used NSUserDefaults before , to store some variables for the settings section of my application.

However now i am making a recipes application , where the user can type in his own recipes and saves them. Each recipe has a title a description a date etc.. So i guess i ll need an array to save every recipe. But how will i add every new recipe dynamically?

I mean i ll just start to save the recipe in the next position on the array? and what happens if the user deletes one recipe and theres a free position in the array?

My logic here is correct on saving the data? What would you do?

Comment: Don't use NSUserDefaults to store user data; that's not what it's for. Look at core data or even property list serialisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is not what you're looking for. Technically it would work for what you want, but you're probably better off just making a custom class that has a property for all of the recipe characteristics and making the class conform to the `<NSCoding>` protocol so that you can convert it to data and write it to a file.

I know that might sound complicated if you've never done it before but it's really not too bad.

[Here's an example for implementing `<NSCoding>`.](http://soff.es/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding) Ignore the end part where it shows you saving the data to `NSUserDefaults`.

To save your data, instead of using NSUserDefaults, [take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497912/problem-writing-nsdata-in-my-device). It might seem like a lot of code for a small task, but the concept is pretty simple.

Edit:

To convert your object to data, assuming you've already implemented `<NSCoding>` in your custom class:

```
YourClass* someObject;

// do whatever you do to fill the object with data

NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:someObject];

/*
 Now we create the path to the documents directory for your app
 */

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

/*
 Here we append a unique filename for this object, in this case, 'Some_Recipe'
 */

NSString* filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"Some_Recipe"];

/*
 Finally, let's write the data to our file
 */

[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

/*
 We're done!
 */
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I created a class as suggested in the tutorial for my recipe object , with all the necessary properties of the class. However i am a bit confused on how i can save the data. I need to create a new object of the recipe class , write my data on it , as given from the user but then how exactly do i save it?

Comment: i mean the answer says smth about getting the documents directory and then make a file name to write the data using this directory. But what is this directory for me? I have an object "recipe" with data , how do i use that to save it in a file ?

Comment: I'll edit my answer with some information more specific to your situation.

Comment: that would be incredible Rickay. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I just implemented it , looks great! Just a few more things. Now if i want to show the data to the user , how do i get them back from the storage? Moreover , how exactly is the data saved ? Like a big array of arrays(recipes) ? And if i want to delete one recipe , how do i do that?

Comment: And when someones stores one recipe and then another etc etc. When he deletes the 2nd recipe he created, the memory will be automatically deallocated? Do i need to specify the next time where the new recipe will be saved? Or all these things are done automatically?

Comment: And something last , you say somewhere that we append a unique file name for this object. Do i have to change this if i have many recipes? Or this file name is an array of recipes?

Comment: You will need a different filename for each recipe, or you could have an array of recipes stored in one file. For the other questions, I think you'll need to work out those details yourself. Good luck!

Comment: But i guess thats what i would like to do right? Have an array of recipes inside the filename. That was the purpose of the question too. How to dynamically save these things. So i guess i musnt change the name every time for every recipe , cause i dont know how man recipes the user wants to create. Or how many of them will delete later and create new ones.